# What is the meaning of :: while calling a method in mfc and c++?

Tags: c++

I have found a code in my project like

```
if(::PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
```

OR

```
if(<Some Condition>)

{
    ::TranslateMessage(&msg);

    ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

What is the significance of ::?

And the code is related to JNI.

Is it because of Threaded programming(I don't know)?

Answer (score 2):

That is the [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/cpp/scope-resolution-operator) specifier.

There is more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp).

> C++ names can be used only in certain regions of a program. This area is called the "scope" of the name. Scope determines the "lifetime" of a name that does not denote an object of static extent. Scope also determines the visibility of a name, when class constructors and destructors are called, and when variables local to the scope are initialized. (For more information, see Constructors and Destructors.) There are five kinds of scope:
>
> - Function scope
> - File scope
> - Class scope
> - Prototype scope

Read those articles for more information.

---

There are lots of [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) about scope too.

> A scope is a region of the program and broadly speaking there are three places, where variables can be declared −
>
> - Inside a function or a block which is called local variables,
> - In the definition of function parameters which is called formal parameters.
> - Outside of all functions which is called global variables.

I should point out that the same rules apply for **functions**. So if a function is defined in, for example, `CDialog`, and you want the **global** version and not the `CDialog` version, you use `::` to access the global version.